# R code for group barchart of the data attached

Tags: r

how do i plot the below data on a group barchart?

```
year    MALE    FEMALE
2009    64  207
2010    88  274
2011    114 304
2012    142 404
2013    188 462
```

Comment: I cannot guess why everyone's answer here was downvoted. If no answer satisfies your question, please comment or use edits on your own post, as we have been given very little information to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `ggplot2`:

```
dat %>% 
    gather(gender, count, MALE:FEMALE) %>% 
    ggplot(., aes(year, count, fill=gender)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

Input data:

```
dat <- structure(list(year = 2009:2013, MALE = c(64L, 88L, 114L, 142L, 
188L), FEMALE = c(207L, 274L, 304L, 404L, 462L)), .Names = c("year", 
"MALE", "FEMALE"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
))
```

Comment: thank you all, you have all gave me all i need. thanks

Comment: @ Adam Quek thank you adam Quek, you gave me what i need, thank you once again, but i still need help to finish the assignment, i want to perform poisson regression on a cancer data obtained in a district, the data is given below:

Answer (score 0):

I guessed what it was that you would like grouped:

```
# With the following data
df <- matrix(c(2009, 64, 207,
               2010, 88,  274,
               2011, 114, 304,
               2012, 142, 404,
               2013, 188, 462), byrow = T, ncol = 3, 
             dimnames = list(1:5,c("year","MALE","FEMALE")))

# The plot
bp <- barplot(height = df[,2:3], # the data (two columns)
              beside = T, # groups them besides one another
              legend = df[,1], # the legend will be time 
              args.legend = list(x = "topleft", # legend location
                                 bty = "n")) # remove legend background
# the text
text(x = bp, # copies the legend which was saved as "bp"
     y = df[,2:3], # y = height, the same as the height in the bar plot function
     labels = df[,2:3], # the height is what we want to read as the text
     xpd = T, # without this as TRUE, the text would be cut off at the top
     pos = 3) # label position, 3 = above (1 = below, 2 = left, 4 = right)

# one way to add a title
title("Male and Female X from 2009 to 2013")
```

[image]